# Python: Newspaper Module - Any way to pool getting articles straight from URLs?

Tags: python, multithreading, parsing, nlp, python-newspaper

I'm using the Newspaper module for python found [here](http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/advanced.html).

In the tutorials, it describes how you can pool the building of different newspapers s.t. it generates them at the same time. (see the "Multi-threading article downloads" in the link above)

Is there any way to do this for pulling articles straight from a LIST of urls? That is, is there any way I can pump in multiple urls into the following set-up and have it download and parse them concurrently?

```
from newspaper import Article
url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/zhongwen/simp/chinese_news/2012/12/121210_hongkong_politics.shtml'
a = Article(url, language='zh') # Chinese
a.download()
a.parse()
print(a.text[:150])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pulling articles straight from urls"? Are you trying to scrape and download all linked articles from a given URL?

Comment: I just want to scrape the url provided for the article on the page.  I want to be able to provide a set of urls so they can be downloaded in tandem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this by creating a `Source` for each article URL. (disclaimer: not a python developer)

```
import newspaper

urls = [
  'http://www.baltimorenews.net/index.php/sid/234363921',
  'http://www.baltimorenews.net/index.php/sid/234323971',
  'http://www.atlantanews.net/index.php/sid/234323891',
  'http://www.wpbf.com/news/funeral-held-for-gabby-desouza/33874572',  
]

class SingleSource(newspaper.Source):
    def __init__(self, articleURL):
        super(StubSource, self).__init__("http://localhost")
        self.articles = [newspaper.Article(url=url)]

sources = [SingleSource(articleURL=u) for u in urls]

newspaper.news_pool.set(sources)
newspaper.news_pool.join()

for s in sources:
  print s.articles[0].html
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is really old but it's one of the first links that shows up when I googled how to get multithread newspaper. While Kyles answer is very helpful, it is not complete and I think it has some typos...

```
import newspaper

urls = [
'http://www.baltimorenews.net/index.php/sid/234363921',
'http://www.baltimorenews.net/index.php/sid/234323971',
'http://www.atlantanews.net/index.php/sid/234323891',
'http://www.wpbf.com/news/funeral-held-for-gabby-desouza/33874572',  
]

class SingleSource(newspaper.Source):
def __init__(self, articleURL):
    super(SingleSource, self).__init__("http://localhost")
    self.articles = [newspaper.Article(url=articleURL)]

sources = [SingleSource(articleURL=u) for u in urls]

newspaper.news_pool.set(sources)
newspaper.news_pool.join()
```

I changed the *Stubsource* to *Singlesource* and one of the *urls* to *articleURL*. 
Of course this just downloads the webpages, you still need to parse them to be able to get the text.

```
multi=[]
i=0
for s in sources:
    i+=1
    try:
        (s.articles[0]).parse()
        txt = (s.articles[0]).text
        multi.append(txt)
    except:
        pass
```

In my sample of 100 urls, this took half the time compared to just working with each url in sequence. (Edit: After increasing the sample size to 2000 there is a reduction of about a quarter.)

(Edit: Got the whole thing working with multithreading!) I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/10193037) very good explanation for my implementation. With a sample size of 100 urls, using 4 threads takes comparable time to the code above but increasing the thread count to 10 gives a further reduction of about a half. A larger sample size needs more threads to give a comparable difference.

```
import newspaper
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def getTxt(url):
    article = Article(url)
    article.download()
    try:
        article.parse()
        txt=article.text
        return txt
    except:
        return ""

pool = ThreadPool(10)

# open the urls in their own threads
# and return the results
results = pool.map(getTxt, urls)

# close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

To build upon Joseph's Valls answer. I'm assuming the original poster wanted to use multithreading to extract a bunch of data and store it somewhere properly. After much trying, I think I have found a solution, it may not be the most efficient but it works, I've tried to make it better however, I think the newspaper3k plugin could be a bit buggy. However, this works in extracting the desired elements to a DataFrame.

```
import newspaper
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import Source
import pandas as pd

gamespot_paper = newspaper.build('https://www.gamespot.com/news/', memoize_articles=False)
bbc_paper = newspaper.build("https://www.bbc.com/news", memoize_articles=False)
papers = [gamespot_paper, bbc_paper]
news_pool.set(papers, threads_per_source=4) 
news_pool.join()

#Create our final dataframe
df_articles = pd.DataFrame()

#Create a download limit per sources
limit = 100

for source in papers:
    #tempoary lists to store each element we want to extract
    list_title = []
    list_text = []
    list_source =[]

    count = 0

    for article_extract in source.articles:
        article_extract.parse()

        if count > limit:
            break

        #appending the elements we want to extract
        list_title.append(article_extract.title)
        list_text.append(article_extract.text)
        list_source.append(article_extract.source_url)

        #Update count
        count +=1


    df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'Title': list_title, 'Text': list_text, 'Source': list_source})
    #Append to the final DataFrame
    df_articles = df_articles.append(df_temp, ignore_index = True)
    print('source extracted')
```

Please do suggest any improvements!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Newspaper module but the following code uses a list of URLs and should be equivalent to the one provided in the linked page:

```
import newspaper
from newspaper import news_pool

urls = ['http://slate.com','http://techcrunch.com','http://espn.com']
papers = [newspaper.build(i) for i in urls]
news_pool.set(papers, threads_per_source=2)
news_pool.join()
```

Comment: This is what I meant by "In the tutorials, it describes how you can pool the building of different newspapers s.t. it generates them at the same time." I don't think this does what i want however. Specifically, I tried doing the same thing but with the urls of specific articles and i don't see how i can extract out the texts of the articles... if it was even downloaded.